# Posts to expire (deleted) after a date

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, automation

I am creating a coupon site from scratch. I have reviewed many code examples on the Internet, but have not found anything that will work, as my requirements are little different.

I need help in creating an expiry function that would delete the "coupon" (post_type) automatically.

As a coupon site, all coupons are imported in bulk, so the expiry date format (e.g. 01/12/2014, 01-12-2014, or 1 Dec 2014) differs from coupon to coupon in a particular import (session). This creates a problem when the date format differs, and it's never the same.

Custom field is "expiry_date", it will store the date.

Does any one have a good solution for this problem?

Comment: You could convert the expiry date into a Unix timestamp [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and then do a simple `if` to check to if it's higher than [`time()`](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) and then hide otherwise. So it wouldn't show up on the site anymore. Physically deleting it from the database is going to require a daily cron job, not sure if that's really necessary, so long as expired coupons don't show on the site. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Deleting coupons is required, as for some coupons we have to make some manual changes from the dashboard and i don't want to make any manual changes to the coupon that will be expired. can you provide the code for the whole function. thanks in advance.

Comment: So do you basically just need to be able to tell the difference between expired coupons and active coupons? You could put the expiry date as the `Published` date for each coupon. Then simply browse the `Scheduled` filter of your coupons. [http://screencast.com/t/E37TWEwU](http://screencast.com/t/E37TWEwU). Then you simply define the `post_status` parameter of [WP_Query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to `future`.

Comment: your idea is nice but , i do require that the expired coupons should be deleted from our database. as we will be having thousands of coupon. so using crons will be the better option for us.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with writing cron jobs but there seem to be a lot of resources on Stack Overflow. This isn't really a Worpress question anymore. You just need a cron job to delete MySQL rows as needed, really nothing to do with WP anymore.

Comment: ok, then kindly provide me with the function for the method you suggested, with the different time format. as i am not a developer, still learning things, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did something similar a while ago. I'm not sure deleting a post is a good solution, maybe you can change only the post status to a custom one called Expired for example. But for an example, the code below will delete the post.

First create a daily cron job:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'delete_expired_coupons_daily' );
function delete_expired_coupons_daily() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'delete_expired_coupons' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'delete_expired_coupons');
    }
}
add_action( 'delete_expired_coupons', 'delete_expired_coupons_callback' );
```

Then use the delete_expired_coupons_callback function to loop through the coupon posts, check for the date and delete if necessary:

```
function delete_expired_coupons_callback() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'coupon',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $coupons = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($coupons->have_posts()):
        while($coupons->have_posts()): $coupons->the_post();    

            $expiration_date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'expiry_date', true );
            $expiration_date_time = strtotime($expiration_date);

            if ($expiration_date_time < time()) {
                wp_delete_post(get_the_ID());
                //Use wp_delete_post(get_the_ID(),true) to delete the post from the trash too.                  
            }

        endwhile;
    endif;
}
```

Couple of suggestions: When you import the coupons, you can do an strtotime conversion, so the date format is the same in the database. This way you don't need to loop through all of the posts to check the expiration date, you can use a custom query to check if its expired, so the daily job will run much faster:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'coupon',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
               'key' => 'expiry_date',
               'value' => time(),
               'compare' => '<'
            )
        )
    );
```

You can create an Expiration post status to simply disable these posts without deleting them: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_status

And you can change the post status like this, instead of the wp_delete_post function:

```
// Update post
$my_post = array();
$my_post['ID'] = get_the_ID();
$my_post['post_status'] = 'expired';

// Update the post into the database
wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: will it work with different time formats.

Comment: The 3 example you showed in the question will work with strtotime, but its not fool-proof. The problem is that 01/12/2014 could be december 1. or january 12, nobody knows 100% sure.

Comment: can you explain where should i put this two codes.

Comment: Oh boy...:) You need some experience with WordPress to do something like this. But the code goes inside your theme's function.php file or create a plugin for it. How and where do you registered the coupon post type for the Coupons?

Comment: My post_type is created using PODs. i will check the code and let you know. thanks

Comment: the code works, but its deleting post slow slow as you mentioned, so how can i do an strtotime conversion at the time of importing, or manually adding a coupon.

Comment: How many coupons do you have? it should't be too slow, since its only going to run once a day.

Comment: around 2000 coupons.

Comment: Hello @passatgt, can You please explain how to send post to draft, instead of deleting it? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest opening CSV in Excel and use formatting to convert all dates to the same format and save CSV before using this for importing. This should avoid any development efforts.